# Endpoint for getting friends who have been to a venue

Tags: foursquare

The website has had for some time now a section that shows friends who have been to a certain venue, yet I do not see an endpoint for getting this information.

Is such an endpoint in the works or is this considered a privacy issue like friends history even though they're both on the website???

Answer (score 0):

There is no API endpoint with this functionality yet. There's a variety of reasons for why this is the case, but the primary one is that it hasn't hit the top of our priority stack just yet (this element of the website was not built off of the API)